# How to properly initialize CefSharp web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome, browser, cefsharp

I am using the CefSharp web browser in my project. But when I switch between two WinForms I got this exception.

> System.Exception: 'CEF can only be initialized once per process. This is a limitation of the underlying CEF/Chromium framework. You can change many (not all) settings at runtime through RequestContext.SetPreference. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception. If you are seeing this unexpectedly then you are likely calling Cef.Initialize after you've created an instance of ChromiumWebBrowser, it must be before the first instance is created.'

Here is the code.

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;


    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(Settings.Default.SetLink);
        this.GpBrwsr.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
    public Form3()
    {
    
        InitBrowser();
    }

    private void browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsLoading == false)
        {
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert('All Resources Have Loaded');");
        }
    }
```

And here is how i am switching between forms.

```
LoginToSettings Login = new LoginToSettings();
Login.Show();
this.Hide();
```

[image: Exception Image]

My question is how do I initialize it so I don't stumble upon this exception?
I also tried "Form Minimization" Option instead of "Form Hiding"
But still the same issue.

I have used this link for using CefSharp browser.
[Code Source for CefSharp](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/how-to-embed-chrome-browser-in-a-winforms-application)

Comment: Please no images of code, see https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You can only call Cef.Initialize once, you can check  Cef.IsInitialized to see if it's already been called. Calling it in your program.cs file is the easiest place in my opinion  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L50 What is unclear about the exception?  This is a genuine question so I can improve the error message if required. In your case as you are not setting any values on CefSettings you don't need to call Cef.Initialize at all.

Comment: @amaitland I am trying to show the google web page through initializing it. Is it not "setting a value"?

Comment: You can safely remove Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings()); in your instance as this is the default. You haven't set any custom settings. If you plan on setting some values on CefSettings then just add an if not Cef.IsInitialized check. You can only call Cef.Initialize once.

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to call `Cef.Initialize(....);`
(of course with some args such as CefSettings obj etc..)

You must call it **before** any creation of a `new ChromiumWebBrowser()` as a creation of the browser will infact *Initialize* Cef with the default settings.

And as you may guess, it will rise an error once you will try call Initialize again as it can only be initialized once.